# A video of 1h27m duration, only plays up to 27m

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg, vlc, mpeg4

## Background

I have recovered some large videos as explained here:

https://superuser.com/q/1686118/571029

There are 3 videos of almost the same size with the same content, apparently:

```bash
> ls recoverit-Wondershare/ -lh
total 23G
-rw-r--r-- 1 m3 users 3.7G Nov 25 20:03 00000084.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 m3 users 3.3G Nov 25 18:10 39289942016.mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 m3 users 3.3G Nov 25 20:30 5142605824.mp4
```

## Problem

The problem is all of the 3 videos could only be played up to 27m. I'm playing by VLC media player. But the video duration according to reported duration by `ffprobe` is 1h27m:

```bash
> ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -sexagesimal recoverit-Wondershare/00000084.mp4 
1:27:14.640000
```

Also, right-click details/properties menu shows that the 1h27m is the duration.

## No fatal erros

I double-check video integrity by the method here:

https://superuser.com/a/100290/571029

By this command:

```bash
> ffmpeg -v fatal -i recoverit-Wondershare/00000084.mp4 -f null - 2>error-fatal.log
```

But there are no fatal error reported in `error-fatal.log`.

## Question

What else can I do to fix/play the videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the recovering process in a wrong way. With a better way of recovering, now, 1h17m of the 1h27m video is recovered. Meaning only the last 10m is *not* recovered. The details are here:

https://superuser.com/a/1691027/571029